# How to call my PHP function with AJAX ? wp_query

Tags: php, wp-query, ajax, javascript

Im trying to build a product filter to display products depending on the tags

this is the function in my function.php

```
function product_filter() {
  $args = array( 
              'post_type'    => 'product', 
              'posts_per_page' => 5, 
              'product_tag'    => $_REQUEST['tags'];
              );
        
        // Create the new query
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        
        // Get products number
        $product_count = $loop->post_count;
        
        // If results
        if( $product_count > 0 ) :
        
          echo '<ul class="products">';
          
            // Start the loop
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); //global $product;
            
              //global $post;
              wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );

              echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($product_id).'">'.get_the_title($product_id).'</a>';
              
              if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) 
                echo  get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); 
              else 
                echo '<img src="'.$woocommerce .'/assets/images/placeholder.png" alt="" width="'.$woocommerce->get_image_size('shop_catalog_image_width').'px" height="'.$woocommerce->get_image_size('shop_catalog_image_height').'px" />';
          
            endwhile;
          
          echo '</ul><!--/.products-->';
        
        else :
        
          _e('No product matching your criteria.');
        
        endif; // endif $product_count > 0
}

add_action('wp_ajax_fetch_posts', 'product_filter');

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_fetch_posts', 'product_fiter');
```

AJAX )- what i currently have on xhttp.open i can figure out what the url is  and i think i would need a if statement in the function.php? something like `if (action=='product_filter")//run product_filter?`

```
function ajax_call_test(tags){
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("POST", product_filter.ajax_url, true); 
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       // Response
       var response = this.responseText;
     }
  };
  var data = {action : "product_filter",$tags : tags};
  xhttp.send( JSON.stringify(data));
```

How can i use AJAX & Vanilla JS to call Product_filter and pass in the tag that i grabbed from the front end to the PHP function?

Comment: look into the REST API in particular this function https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/ that will give you a pretty URL you can ping, but if you want to fetch posts, there's already an endpoint at `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts` that you can use to fetch a list of posts with URL parameters for filters. The old admin ajax API is difficult to debug and has lots of gotchas, the REST API will tell you in human readable text if something goes wrong

Comment: @TomJNowell cant use API that would require the user to be logged in and i have been looking for the api key for past 30 minutes and cant find it in my local dev profile if i can find it i can query it from php and just drop the json file down to the front end

Comment: you can use the REST API without being logged in, e.g. http://tomjn.test/wp-json/wp/v2/posts, of course you'll need a login to create posts or update them, and there's nothing stopping you creating an unauthenticated endpoint to do that too. As for API keys I don't know what you're referring to, that's not how the REST API authentication works out of the box, but as I said earlier, you don't need authentication

Comment: i got the original fetch to work but want to look into the api too

this is the return i got from querying the  WC API since im trying to pull products ill use woocommerce's API 
```{
  "code": "woocommerce_rest_cannot_view",
  "message": "Sorry, you cannot list resources.",
  "data": {
    "status": 401
  }
}
```
using ```wp-json/wc/v3/products``` i guess im remembering it wrong looks like a https/http issue thx tho gonna go over the docs and see if i can figure this out ```https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#authentication-over-https```

Comment: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/